# How do city states' gold investment quests work?

Tags: civilization-5

I was playing Civilization V Brave New World and a notice popped to the right saying that the city-state of Genoa will appreciate gold investment at the moment (20 turns remaining) and will return 50% profit.

I thought if I give them a huge amount of gold like 3000 gold they will return 4500 to me. After some turns I noticed that I didn't get the big flow of gold. I checked the city-state and noticed the gold investment quest is not there anymore.

How do these gold investment quests work?

Answer (score 13):

Investment quests grant additional influence from donations to the city state (IE, if a 1000 gold donation normally grants 50 influence, you will gain 75 influence if you donate 1000 gold during a public works project quest), there is no direct way to get money back from a city state.

Comment: But you do get other benefits if they are friendly or allied like resources, units, culture, etc and they will go to war with you if you're allied.

Comment: @Foosh Yes, but I figured that including that was outside the scope of the question, and it's true regardless of how you gain the influence.  If the OP would like an analysis of city states I'm more than happy to write it, they happen to be my forte.

Answer (score -2):

The idea is something like this: investing in a mercantile city state will help you increase your civ's happiness, and in doing so will allow for greater population growth within your civ, which will in turn allow for you to grow your gold reserves more quickly. I've logged nearly 2000 hours playing the Sid Meiers packages: and this is the best advice I can give you; pull out a piece of paper and document all of the cause and effects of the game!  It's great fun if you are of an analytical mindset.

Happy playing!

Comment: Ok, but this doesn't answer the question (how do gold investment quests work).

Comment: i think he did answer the question i asked 50% investment means you for 1000 gold you get 75 influence instead of 50 and not you get your gold plus 50%

Comment: @dipharoh Yes, the *other* answer did. Not this one.